# control the normal on-off positions of the relay without switching off the power supply

Tags: relay

I want to use an eleven pin relay as a on/off switch, and i found a trouble in controlling the normal on-off state.
how i control the normal on-off positions of the relay without switching off the power supply ????

Comment: Welcome to SE. Your question is lacking information such as (1) part number (with link to data sheet), (2) a circuit schematic of how you're using it (use the _Schematic_ button on the editor toolbar and (3) an explanation of what you expect to happen and what is actually happening. Add information for (1), (2) and (3) **in the question** and not in the comments.

Comment: What is the part number of your relay, what do you want the normal on and off states to be, and how do you want to control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relay either has normal on-off positions, or is broken. There is nothing to 'control'.

You get the 'on' position by applying more than the minimum power for on, which you can find out in the data sheet.

You get the 'off' position by applying less than the max power for off, which is also in the data sheet.

For example, a relay **rated** at 24v might turn on for any voltage above 15v, and may need perhaps less than 5v to turn off. These are typical figures, YMMV.